# Can't activate jigoshop wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, jigoshop

I want to install the wordpress jigoshop plugin but I am getting the following error when trying to activate the plugin. I have tried by commenting the line but it generates more errors.

> Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /............/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/gateways/paypal.php on line 21

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

it means you have too old php version - they require 5.3

Comment: My current php version is 5.3.28 & I've checked with 5.4 also.